# Simple transaction query but has syntax error

Tags: mysql

I am trying some sammple query in mysql client but the transaction syntax does not work]

```
 MySQL  database-2:3306 ssl  TestDb  SQL > START TRANSACTION
                                                                                         -> select * from mvcc where glyph = 'a'
                                                                                         -> COMMIT
                                                                                         -> ;
```

And it reports syntax error :

```
ERROR: 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'select * from mvcc where glyph = 'a'
COMMIT' at line 2
```

This seems to be a very simple query and it's too easy to understand why it fails. I can run the select statement without any issue. Any idea?

Answer (score 0):

You need a semicolon at the end of each of the queries.

```
START TRANSACTION;
SELECT * FROM mvcc WHERE glyph = 'a';
COMMIT;
```

Comment: the sql terminated if I add semicolon after the select query

Comment: What do you mean 'terminated'? Did it give an error message?

Comment: I have fixed the answer. You need a semicolon at the end of the `START TRANSACTION` line also.

Comment: tried the new answer and get
```start transaction;
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.0247 sec)``` Basically it complete with semicolon in the first line and does not treat the clause as transaction..

Comment: Please look at https://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-transaction.aspx. A transaction is made up of `START TRANSACTION;`, a number of other queries, and `COMMIT;`. Each query needs to end with a semicolon. The DB is meant to do exactly what you observed.